# Why shlex.split() removes path separator or doubles it?

Tags: python-3.x

Working with `shelex.split()` to pass arguments to `subprocess.Popen()`. I got path separator removed if not specifying `posix=False`. Here is sample program and output:

```
print(os.getcwd())
print(shlex.split(os.getcwd()))
print(shlex.split(os.getcwd(), posix=False))

C:\Dev\Ws\OnPremise\master\cmake
['C:DevWsOnPremisemastercmake']
['C:\\Dev\\Ws\\OnPremise\\master\\cmake']
```

Some external programs are sensitive to double backslash. Ordinary `string.split()` worked in those cases but fails if path contains space.
How to split command line and get single path separator and correct path if it contains space?